# What am I doing wrong in this C code I've written

Tags: c

The problem:
Given two integers a and b, which can be positive or negative, find the sum of all the integers between and including them and return it. If the two numbers are equal return a or b.

The answer I'm expecting for the below solution is 14. But no matter what I change it always shows 5

My Solution:

```
int get_sum(int a , int b)
{
  int d = a;

  if ( a > b)
    {
      for ( int i = b; i == a; i++)
        {
          d = d + i ;
        }
      return d;
    }

  if ( a < b )
    {
      for ( int i = a; i == b; i++)
        {
          d = d + i;
        }
      return d;
    }
return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
printf("%i", get_sum(5,-1));
}
```

Comment: `for ( int i = b; i == a; i++)` doesn't do what you think it does. Throw some printfs in to trace where the program is going...

Comment: This is the time to learn one of the most important arts of a developer: debugging. Single step through your code and watch your variables and flow of control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct solution to your problem:

```
int get_sum(int a , int b)
{
  int d;

  if ( a > b)
  {
    d = b;
    
    for ( int i = b+1; i <= a; i++)
        
      d = d + i ;
    
    return d;
  }

  else if ( a < b )
  {
    d = a;

    for ( int i = a+1; i <= b; i++)

        d = d + i;
    
    return d;
  }

  else return a;
}

int main (void)
{
printf("%i", get_sum(5,-1));
}
```

The spots where your code has errors are:

1. You initialized `d=a`, but in your case a > b, so it should be `d=b`. If a < b, then it should be `d=a`. So you need to put the proper initialization inside the `if-else` conditions.
2. You used the `for` loop as `for (int i = b; i==a; i++)`. Since you would have already initialized `d=b` inside `if`, so initializing `i=b` erroneously adds `b` to `d` twice. So Initialize `i=b+1` or `i=a+1`.
3. The condition that you used in `for` loop is `i==a` or `i==b`, which is not true at the beginning of the loop, meaning your loop won't run at all. So change it to `i<=a` or `i<=b`.

I also added `return a` at the end, in case `a==b` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You for loop is not working properly due to the condition

```
    int get_sum(int a , int b)
{
  int d = 0;

  if ( a > b)
    {
      for ( int i = b; i <= a; i++)
        {
          d = d + i ;
        }
      return d;
    }

  if ( a < b )
    {
      for ( int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        {
          d = d + i;
        }
      return d;
    }
return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
printf("%i", get_sum(5,-1));
}
```

It now works as you want, iterate through all integers between a and b.
Also, you have to set d to 0.

Comment: Why are you doing `int d=a;`? It should be `int d=0;`.